# How to get parameters for DREIDING force field

Tags: parameters, chemistry, lammps

I am trying to use the DREIDING force field for a polymer. How can i get the parameters for DREIDING?
E.g. if i have ETHYLENE. What are the parameters for the force field? Is there any Data Bank to get them or any software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DREIDING parameters are described in [Stephen L. Mayo, Barry D. Olafson, and William A. Goddard, *J. Phys. Chem.* **1990**, *94*, 8897–8909: "DREIDING: a generic force field for molecular simulations"](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/j100389a010). In which format you need the parameters depends much on the software you want to use for the simulation. You may also want to check out benchmark/application papers like [James P. Ewen, Chiara Gattinoni, Foram M. Thakkar, Neal Morgan, Hugh A. Spikes, Daniele Dini, *Materials* **2016**, *9(8)*, 651.: "A Comparison of Classical Force-Fields for Molecular Dynamics Simulations of Lubricants"](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/28773773/). They used LAMMPS for the simulations.

If you are looking for advice on suitable software or more detailed setup instructions, [Chemistry Stackexchange](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/) (under the molecular-dynamics tag) will probably be a better place for this questions.